# App force close clearing up SQLite entries

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios7

I have created SQLite db using following approach. When user first login I insert few records to this DB. On subsequent logins I use this information for further processing. This is working fine as long as user don't force close app using [approach described here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5137).

If user force close and login to app again, all the information he/she entered was lost. Now my question is, how can I make sure "force close" won't wipe out my data? Any help appreciated.

**onViewLoad, create table if required:**

```
//Database code start.
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingString:@"users.db"]];

    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;

    rc = sqlite3_open_v2([_databasePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
    }
    else
    {
        char * query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS(username TEXT, userid INTEGER NOT NULL)";
        char * errMsg;
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);

        if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
        }

        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    //END of table creation.
```

on "Login button click"

```
//Start SQLite DB operation.
                        sqlite3* db = NULL;
                        int rc=0;
                        rc = sqlite3_open_v2([_databasePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
                        if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
                        {
                            sqlite3_close(db);
                            NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                   @"INSERT INTO USERS(username, userid) values (\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                                                   uName,uID];
                            char * errMsg;
                            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, [insertSQL UTF8String] ,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
                            if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"Failed to insert record  rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
                            }
                            sqlite3_close(db);
                        }

                        //End of sqlite DB operation.
```

As long as user don't forceclose app, data didn't wipe out.

**EDIT:**

After spending lot of hours I see that folder paths are correct, but I am getting "unable to open database file" issue on phone.

Comment: We're going to need more information about what your app does with the SQLite database. SQLite actually has a pretty good reputation for being tolerant of unexpected terminations. From their web site: "An SQLite database is highly resistant to corruption. If an application crash, or an operating-system crash, or even a power failure occurs in the middle of a transaction, the partially written transaction should be automatically rolled back the next time the database file is accessed." From: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html Perhaps its as simple as committing more often? Hard to say.

Comment: Yeah, about the only thing I can think of is that you start a transaction and never end it until the app closes.

Comment: @ipmcc: "about what your app does with the SQLite database'-> You mean, queries. In my case SQLite has simple table (users) with 4 columns. As soon as login successful, I insert data into this table. Every time when user opens my app, will check this table to see if data available or not, if not redirect to login page, because I don't have enough data to make decisions.

Comment: @HotLicks: Your guess is, some long transaction, which never closed might corrupted the db on "force close", is that correct?

Comment: It wouldn't "corrupt" the DB.  By design everything done under the transaction would be "rolled back".

Comment: @HotLicks: I see, make sense. Let me closely look at my code tonight. Thanks!

Comment: If you're not starting a transaction anywhere then that's likely not the problem, but if you blindly copied some code from somewhere you may very well be starting the transaction.

Comment: @HotLicks: As far as I remember, I am not starting any transaction explicitly, but will check my code to make sure not doing anything silly there

Comment: You start a transaction with [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), and if you don't subsequently perform `COMMIT TRANSACTION` then everything done in the transaction will be "rolled back".

Comment: @HotLicks, Will confirm tonight. If I am doing this mistake, will close this questions tonight.

Comment: I have updated question with more code. I don't have any transactions in code (unless I am misunderstood something)

Comment: If it's not that I suspect that you have a file path problem.

Comment: I am leaning towards file path problem too, not sure how I can debug it.

Comment: NSLog the file path at every step.  And when you go to display it in a command entry window, make sure you're displaying the right one (which is not necessarily the same one you displayed on the last run).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have MAC (to connect my phone) and debugging this behaviour which is happening only phone becoming little bit challenging. Is there any way we can retrieve NSLog entries on phone?

Comment: You can fetch the NSLog history from the phone, but you need a Mac to fetch it.  In a pinch you could write a crude log to a regular file in the file system, but you'd then need some means to display that file.

Comment: I think another interesting thing i can do could be, print this path in my screens. Right now we are in beta testing, so this approach shouldn't be a problem. Let me try it. Thanks!

Comment: It seems folder paths are correct, but I am getting "unable to open database file" issue on phone.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long painful debug cycle I nailed down this issue:

```
 _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingString:@"users.db"]];
```

should be:

```
 _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.db"]];
```

Surprisingly first approach worked fine in simulator and most of the examples on internet like [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_7_Application) use first approach.